# PostgreSQL logic/query for user LIKES

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I'm very new to postgreSQL and i want to INCREMENT a field by 1 or DECREMENT it by 1 ( similar to firestore FieldValue.increment(1) )

**Scenario**: Lets assume a post(column in a table) has value 10 and 5 users try to INCREMENT it by 1 at same time. I want the updated post value to be 15 and not 11. How can i do this with postgreSQL?

Tech stack: PostgreSQL Express NodeJS React

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You _probably_ shouldn't be storing "likes" in a single scalar value - instead you should have a table that stores every like `+1` or dislike `-1` that get added. You can get the actual score by doing `SUM` over that table (filtered by post). For performance you would use an indexed-view or row containing cached data which would be copied from the `SUM` automatically by your RDBMS. I recommend you complete a course in database theory (especially database table normalization).

Comment: Thanks for your comment mate it's helpful. But is there any other way to do this because hear i am creating a new table just to store likes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to know who liked what, right? Otherwise somebody could "like" something twice or "unlike" something they never liked.

So have a table to store likes of a person for an post like this:

```
CREATE TABLE likes (
   person_id bigint REFERENCES persons NOT NULL,
   post_id bigint REFERENCES posts NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (person_id, post_id)
);

CREATE INDEX ON likes (post_id);
```

Each "like" is an entry in this table.

The primary key guarantees that nobody can "like" the same post more than once, and the index makes it possible to find all people who like a certain post quickly.

The transactional guarantees of a relational database will make sure that even if two people insert a row at the same time, only one of them will succeed.

You can find your desired count like this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM likes
WHERE post_id = 12345;
```

Comment: Exercise for the reader: add support for dislikes :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And i have one more question but not related to this increment. How many table can i have in postgreSQL. If i create 500 Tables will it decrease performance.

Comment: The number of tables has very little effect on performance (yes micro seconds of overhead to properly identify the table) , it is how they are accessed that performance depends.  BTW 500 tables is a relatively small database.

Comment: 500 tables is fine. But the question is justified: once you get into the 10000s, the performance of some metadata queries (which is important) will suffer.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I consider myself lucky, but I've never encountered a production database with more than ~100 tables or so. If a database had 500+ tables that suggests the application might be experiencing scope-creep - or someone forgot to delete their ETL tables after their SSIS job completed. Forgive my lack of imagination, but what kind of data model requires 500+ tables to store data? (and I assume it's correctly normalized?)

Comment: @Dai I agree. I meant that 500 tables won't be a performance problem.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe based on your experience, would select count(*) from likes become pretty slow as things grow? I'd imagine select count(*) on an Instagram post for example, would slow queries down quite a bit (because of millions/billons of likes in the table) even with proper indices but maybe I'm wrong? What's your take on it?

Comment: @HummingBird24 Not knowing the query and the data, I cannot comment.